# Simplify these "basis functions" for universal computation?

Tags: computability, function-and-relation-composition

[**Background**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1381743/16397): The following three functions (which map naturals to naturals) form a "complete basis" for universal computation, in the sense that any Turing machine can be simulated by iterating some finite composition of instances of these functions with some initial value of $n$:
$$\begin{align}
f_0(n) & = n + [n>0][n\ \text{even}]\ 2^{|n|_2} \\
f_1(n) & = n + [n>0][n\ \text{even}]\ 2^{|n|_2 + 1}\\
f_2(n) & =  [n>0] \left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor 
\end{align}$$
where $[...]$ are [Iverson brackets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) and $|n|_2 = \lfloor\log_2(n+1)\rfloor$ is the number of digits in the [bijective base-2 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijective_numeration) of n.

**Question**: Does the same result hold for the following three functions (which are approximations to $f_0,f_1,f_2$ respectively)? ... 
$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}_0(n) & = n + [n \text{ is even}]\ n  &= 2n \text{ IF }n \text{ is even ELSE }n\\
\hat{f}_1(n) & = n + [n \text{ is even}]\ 2n &= 3n\text{ IF }n \text{ is even ELSE }n\\
\hat{f}_2(n) & =  \left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor 
\end{align}
$$

(Or perhaps the number of functions can be reduced without introducing undue  complexity?)

**NB**: I don't know if this can be related, but [it can be shown](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/522609/16397) that the functions

$$\begin{align}
f(n) &= 3 n\\
g(n) &= \left \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \right \rfloor
\end{align}$$

are such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{N_+}$, there exists a composition $F = g \circ g \circ \cdots \circ g \circ f \circ f \cdots \circ f $ with $\ y = F(x)$.

**Motivation**: The functions $f_0,f_1,f_2$ are designed to arithmetically mimic the exact behavior of three extremely simple operations on binary strings, which are nevertheless sufficient to simulate any Turing machine. It seems likely that simpler arithmetic operations can accomplish the same thing, although the proof may be elusive.

Comment: The fact that the 3 initial functions are considering integers as queues and the 3 other functions consider integers as stacks makes me feel that it will not work with them. Especially because with only one stack, you can't be Turing equivalent. But you can with one queue.

Comment: @Xoff - I don't think that argument applies here. One starts with a single natural number $n$ and some composition $F$ of the basis functions, and the successive iterates $F^k(n)$ simulate the successive configurations of a Turing machine. (The situation is similar to Conway's FRACTRAN, in which a single function that maps naturals to naturals is iterated, with the iterates simulating successive states of a universal register machine.)

Comment: Isn't any function formed by iterating some finite composition of instances of these functions total? Whereas some TMs' functions aren't total?

Comment: @QuinnCulver - Your wording is tricky. Any composition $F$ of the basis functions is *total*, but the *iterates* $F^k(n)$ may serve to define a *partial* function, by way of the fact that for some initial arguments the iterates may never reach a fixpoint (which would signify halting of the simulated TM).

Comment: @QuinnCulver - (cont'd) The situation is related to the fact that a TM may be described by a single unbounded search of the form `while c not in H: c -> t(c)`, where `c` is the complete configuration of the system, `H` is a set of halting configurations, and `t()` is the so-called Turing transformation *which is primitive recursive* (and hence total). I.e., a TM computes a partial function by means of iterations of a (total) primitive recursive function.

Comment: @r.e.s. OK, what's an *iterate*?

Comment: @QuinnCulver - See [iterated function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition). Here the quantities $n, F(n), F(F(n)), F(F(F(n))),\dots$ are the successive *iterates* of $F$ (which maps naturals to naturals), with initial argument $n$. The $k$th such iterate is typically denoted $F^k(n)$ for $k = 0,1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: @r.e.s. Would you happen to have any updated information on this question? If not, I might start a bounty.

Comment: @user1667423 - I'm unaware of any new information relevant to this question. I've never created a bounty before, so allow me to make this my first.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a universal program-machine ([Minsky machine](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Minsky_machine)) with only one register that uses only the operations of multiplication and (conditional) division by integers 2 and 3. See section 14.2 in [this paper](http://www.cba.mit.edu/events/03.11.ASE/docs/Minsky.pdf) by Minsky.

See also Minsky's model in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-machine_model#1961:_Minsky.27s_model_of_a_partial_recursive_function_reduced_to_a_.22program.22_of_only_two_instructions).